# Changing default permissions for wget?

Tags: permissions, php, wget

I'm using a PHP script to call `shell_exec` and execute `wget` to download some files to `/var/www/dir/`. (Internal tool, so security isn't much of an issue)

The directory has `777` permissions. But when I run `wget`, all of the files are `644` by default. Ideally, I would like `665` for group write access for group `www-data`.

How do I set the permissions for `wget` downloaded files? I don't want to run `chmod -R` after every call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions that are applied to new files that get created are controlled by the user's umask in a given shell. You can see what they are using the command `umask`.

```
$ umask
0002
```

To get the permissions of these new files set to 665 you'll need to set the umask to this:

```
$ umask 112
```

This will enable all the bits in rwxrwxrwx, enabling the bits rw-rw-r-x. The mask is specifying which bits to "mask" so that they're disabled.

#### Incorporating using shell_exec

You could do something like this to enable the `umask` using `shell_exec` in PHP:

```
"umask 112; ...wget..."
```

The semicolon above designates that these are actually 2 commands. The `umask` will run first, followed by the second command `wget ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `umask` temporarily before issuing `wget`.